# Will mongodb simplify geometry like PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, mongodb

I use the [ST_Simplify()](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Simplify.html) function in PostGIS, and am moving to a new geostack with mongodb. Does it have a comparable function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there are [three](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/#geospatial-commands) (well looks like two really) GeoSpatial commands in MongoDB. One is nearest and the other is search. I guess simplification is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: OK. I thought I was missing something. Many thanks, iant.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your data before saving them into mongodb. 
I use the node.js mapshaper library to achieve this.

The main challenge (in my view) with simplified geojson data is that mongodb does not support more than one index pr. collection.